# Concatenate string variables with result from variable

Tags: string, variables, nginx, concatenation

I need to get a var from another var in BASH, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
IP_100="192.168.0.1"
PORT="100"
VAR="\$IP_${PORT}"
echo $VAR
```

returns $IP_100, but still ... I want to evaluate that var in order to get "192.168.0.1", in PHP I can do it by $$VAR but not in bash.

I can't evaluate the var first, I'm trying to use this in nginx which has the same bash logic.

Comment: ``VAR="$IP_${PORT}"``  unless I misunderstand your question, simple interpolation will work?

Comment: It doesn't evaluate the var, returns just "100", I need it to return the IP set in IP_100 var -> 192.168.0.1